# When i try add a comment I get this error "Undefined variable $post_id"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have created a blog where i need only authenticated user to leave their comment, i see everything as correct but when I insert data i get an error "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$post->id' "

Form

```
<div class="header">
                <h2>Leave Comment</h2>
                <form action="{{route('post.comment')}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                   
 
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$post_id}}">
           <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control input-group-item" required="required">
            <button class="btn btn_success uppercase input-group-item btn_float"><i class="lab la-telegram"></i></button>
           
            <p>Retrieve comment goes here</p>

                <h5>Commenter:</h5>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
  public function storeComent(Request $request){
  $post =Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();
            PostComment::create([
                'post_id'=>$request->post_id,
                'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
                'comment'=>$request->comment, 

            ]);
            
           return redirect()->back()->with('massage','Comment added successfully'); 
        }
```

Model

```
    use HasFactory;
        protected $guarded = [];
    
        public function comment(){
             return $this->belongsTo(Post::class,'post_id','id');
         }
        public function usercomment(){
             return $this->hasMany(User::class,'user_id','id');
         }
```

Comment: Before you make any changes, configure Laravel so you can see an error message about `$post_id`. I don't know Laravel but there's probably a debug or dev mode you failed to enable.

Comment: here is what i get after updated
 SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$post->id' for column dda.post_comments.post_id

Comment: Couple obvious issues here... 1) `value="$post->id">` - This will literally send the value `'$post->id'` to your backend. That should be `value="{{ $post->id }}"`. 2) `'post_id' => $post_id,` - That would be fine, if you had a variable named `$post_id`, which you do not. You have `$post`, so it should be `'post_id' => $post->id,` (same as on the Front End).

Comment: @TimLewis i get and error Undefined variable $post

Comment: Where? You have multiple files where `$post` is being referenced; which one(s) did you change, and where is this error being triggered? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77123350/edit) with the new code and new error. We don't have access to your code, so when you make a change and then say "that didn't work", we can't help you **unless you show your new code**.

Comment: In the line `$post =Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();` where is the `$post_id` from? Assign value to this first. If the value of `$post_id` is from the input, then based on your question, it should be `$request->post_id`

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is with `$request->id`,
you are not passing id from your form that's why that condition is going invalid.

maybe you can pass hidden input something like this

```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
```

and in controller you can check something like this

```
 public function storeComent(Request $request){
   dd($request->all()); // To make sure that you are getting all request data that you need 
   .......
```

you can also use Log facade to capture your request body

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; // put this at the top
public function storeComent(Request $request){
   Log::($request->all()); // To make sure that you are getting all request data that you need 
   .......
```

Comment: Surely OP should already have access to the post's ID as the comment is posted on the post's page

Comment: here is what i get after updated
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$post->id' for column `dda`.`post_comments`.`post_id` at row 1